# How can I retrieve detail disclosure button's view?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with cells on it with detail disclosure indicator (UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton).

I need the detail disclosure button's view (to show some custom popup menu from it), but it is always null. Why?

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[self showMenu: cell.accessoryView];
NSLog(@"%@",cell.accessoryView);}
```

How an I retrieve disclosure button's view as UIVIew*?
(note, i have the disclosure buttons and tap event is fired for it)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about you connect an outlet from the disclosure button?

Comment: Table is not static, I have a lot of cells by dynamic data and all of them have detail disclosure buttons

Comment: Try cell.accessoryType;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the accessory button by checking the cells subviews:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //[self showMenu: cell.accessoryView];
    NSLog(@"%@",cell.accessoryView);

    NSArray *subviews = [cell subviews];

    for (UIView *subview in subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            NSLog(@"This is that button");
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Subviews: %@", subviews);
}
```

Comment: And what, if I have more buttons in my cell? Is it really the way to do it? Seems so strange for me

Comment: @Tom Well I thought the same thing, but those buttons if added correctly should be in your cell.contentView, not just as a subview to the cell itself.

Comment: Your method returns the same UIButton for every cells...with same position as well (<UIButton: 0x1fd075c0; frame = (277 0; 43 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1fd07680>>)

Comment: It shouldn't be. Each button from the cell should have the same frame, of course, but the actual object is not the same. 2 runs of mine are <UIButton: 0x8d8c1f0; frame = (277 0; 43 43); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8d8c340>> and <UIButton: 0x8d8e510; frame = (277 0; 43 43); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8d87de0>>. You can see they are different.

Comment: @Tom If your method looks exactly like the one I just edited above then I'm sure this method will give you the button for each cell. It is definitely not the same one each time.