# How can I retrieve detail disclosure button's view in ios 7?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7, xcode5

Here, I'm trying to get the view of an accessoryButton in **ios7**.
My issue is similar to this one, but in a different version as I'm upgrading an ios 6 app to ios 7,

[how can I retrieve detail disclosure buttons view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795651/how-can-i-retrieve-detail-disclosure-buttons-view#_=_)

This work fine in **ios 6**, but it doesn't work in ios **7**, I wonder why... here's my code:

```
- (UIView *)accessoryOfCell:(UITableViewCell *)tableViewCell
//Code inside method. I don't know how to quick indent so forget this {}

if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
    for (UIView *view in [tableViewCell subviews]) {
    //this loop 1 times, return view has class UITableViewCellScrollView
        for (UIView *subview in [view subviews]) {
        //this loop 3 times, return subview as:
        //UITableViewCellContentView, _UITableViewCellSeparatorView , UITableViewCellDetailDisclosureView
            NSLog(@"%@", subview.class);
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                return view;
            }
        }
    }
}
else {
// in ios 6, this works super fine!
    for (UIView *view in [tableViewCell subviews]) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            return view;
        }
    }
}
return nil;
```

So with my code above won't return anything as UIButton  in ios7.

NOTE: the "tableViewCell.accessoryView" return nil, I wonder why, since I choose detail disclosure in storyboard.

Any idea please?

EDIT NOTE: 
I can as well put the code like this:

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
    return ((UIView *)tableViewCell.subviews[0]).subviews[2];
} else { ... }
```

But I don't wanna, since this may cause update app in the future a pain in the @$$

EDIT NOTE #2: 
This method is being called inside

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
...
}
```

Comment: I think unless you explicitly set the accessory view, you wont get it back?

Comment: But as in code for ios 6, I don't need to return tableViewCell.accessoryView. Furthurmore, in both version, that accessoryView return nil. Also, I don't want to set accessoryView, since I have many tableViews with different kind of accessory, but using same the parent class, this custom class. Think of this as an abstract class :)